# How to create custom archive page on Tumblr

Tags: html, css, tumblr

I am creating custom Tumblr blog layout: http://thespektrdev.tumblr.com/

I need to create a separated page with all posts (such as archive). But I have not found any way to change standard Tumblr archive page.

What I have tried:

1. Create new page (but how to render all posts on these page when they use theme html). I have not found "Custom template option"
2. Just use css/js switcher. But in this option I should load all posts (it's slow)

Or maybe my situation is impossible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's impossible to change the `/archive` page of a Tumblr blog as Tumblr does not provide the capability.

Comment: Thanks. But not usefull. Maybe you know the Way, how can I create my custom Archive page (it can has separated url /foobar).

Comment: There's nothing here http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes that lets you browse older posts by month or year.